# Adding publishing page by powershell and custom page layout giving error

Tags: 2013, powershell, page-layout

I created custom html page layout with embedded web part in it. When I am trying to add page to pages library by powershell getting below error

```
Fail: Exception calling "AddPublishingPage" with "2" argument(s): "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."
```

at `$Page = $PubWeb.AddPublishingPage($PageName, $PageLayout)`

Strange part is. When I create page manually with same page layout its getting created and once I create it manually. My Script is working fine. I can create pages withouts error once I create page manually.

Not sure what is happning here

Script below :

```
     $PageTitle = $newPage.NewPageTitle
     $Layouts = $PubSite.GetPageLayouts($False)
         foreach($layout in $Layouts){
             if($layout.Name -eq $PageLayoutRelUrl){
                 $PageLayout = $layout
             }
         }
    $Page = $PubWeb.AddPublishingPage($PageName, $PageLayout)
    $Page.Title = $PageTitle
    $Page.Update();
    $Page.CheckIn("Deployment CheckIn")
    $Page.ListItem.File.Publish("Deplyment Pulish")
```

Comment: Please post your current script!

Comment: Added part of script which actually create page and takes page layout.

Answer (score 0):

In your script, you have defined the `$PageLayout` but you didn't define the  `$PageName` so you got this error

> Fail: Exception calling "AddPublishingPage" with "2" argument(s): "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

Try to define the `$PageName` as the following

```
 $PageName = "Test.aspx"
```

Then use it at

```
$Page = $PubWeb.AddPublishingPage($PageName, $PageLayout)
```

Comment: I added part of script. $pageName has value coming similar as "Test.aspx". If  you notice strange part with same script I am able to create pages if first create manually with that page layout in Pages library.